# ExecutenonQuery not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, executenonquery

I have stored proc as below:

```
ALTER PROC pr_Update_Users_Nomination
(
      @UserID AS VARCHAR(100),  
      @Nominated AS BIT
)
AS

UPDATE User
SET isNominated = @Nominated
WHERE 
EMPID = @UserID;
```

I want to call this procedure from c# code: Below is the code I am trying:

```
void OpenConnection()
{
string Nominated = "False";
    //Connection String
        string sConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection mySqlCon = new SqlConnection(sConnString);
        SqlCommand mySqlCom = mySqlCon.CreateCommand();

        //Call the stored proc and provide in parameters
        mySqlCom.CommandText = "EXECUTE pr_Update @UserID @Nominated";
        mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = UserID;
        mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Nominated", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Nominated;

        mySqlCon.Open();
        mySqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mySqlCon.Close();
}
```

I get an error saying

```
Incorrect Syntax near @Nominated
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, when executing a procedure with parameter(*s*), separate the parameters with a comma

```
EXECUTE pr_Update @UserID, @Nominated
```

second, modify your code into this,

```
    string sConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString1"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection mySqlCon = new SqlConnection(sConnString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand mySqlCom = new SqlCommand())
        {
            mySqlCom.Connection = mySqlCon;
            mySqlCom.CommandText = "pr_Update";
            mySqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = UserID;
            mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Nominated", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Nominated;
            try
            {
                mySqlCon.Open();
                mySqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                // do something with the exception
                // don't hide it
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a comma (,) between the parameters.

It should be

```
mySqlCom.CommandText = "EXECUTE pr_Update @UserID, @Nominated";
mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = UserID;
mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Nominated", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Nominated;
```

Alternatively, since all you are doing is calling a stored proc, you could do:

```
mySqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
mySqlCom.CommandText = "pr_Update"; //no need to specify parameter names
mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = UserID;
mySqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Nominated", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Nominated;
```

Answer (score 4):

Give only name of stored procedure, as you are adding parameter in statements after this. Also set CommandType.

```
 mySqlCom.CommandText = "pr_Update";
 mySqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Don't forget to set mySqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Comment: Thanks @Fabio GouW, I was doing that mean while.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking wrong SQL. You should set the command text of command to `pr_Update` only:

```
mySqlCom.CommandText = "pr_Update";
```

And set type command type to stored procedure:

```
mySqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

See [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171921%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more.

Comment: Then how will i send my In parameters ?

Comment: The way you did it. Only setting the `CommandText` was wrong.