# ExecuteNonQuery not working but the ExecuteReader is working

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

First don't mark it as duplicate, because this

[ExecutenonQuery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381318/executenonquery-not-working)

[ExecutenonQuery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381318/executenonquery-not-working)

[ExecuteNonQuery not working in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903412/executenonquery-not-working-in-c-sharp)

is not the solution i am looking, the syntax is correct, the connection also correct because the `SqlDataReader` is working, and i open the connection and called it in `SqlCommand`. Here is my code

```
            if (sql_con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sql_con.Open();
            }
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

            query.Append(String.Format("update tbl_userdata set stage=@stage where username=@name"));

            SqlCommand sql_command2 = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), sql_con);
            sql_command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stage", stage);
            sql_command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", lblName.Text.ToLower());
            sql_command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And after debugging my query is `update tbl_userdata set stage=@stage where username=@name`

i don't know what's wrong here, i remove the `where clause` to see if thats the cause of the problem, but still error. I don't know what's wrong here

here is my connection

```
SqlConnection sql_con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbCon);
```

Sorry i forgot to put my error, the error is the stage is not updating, 
this is my table

```
tbl_userdata
+--------+-------+-------+
|Username|stage  | coins |
+--------+-------+-------+


Username = nvarchar(5), stage = smallint, coins = smallmoney
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? What are your column types and what is your parameter values? Is your update query works on your sql server?  Did you debug your code? What is your query looks like when you add parameter values to your query?

Comment: Have you used SQL profiler? Does command really sent to server?

Comment: And it doesn't throw any exceptions? Are you sure you are sending different stage value than what's already in database?

Comment: The update isn't relevant. That's the table schema, not an error message.

Comment: there are no exceptions, and yes i am sending diffent value, the stage variable is 2

Comment: Instead of assuming some strange behaviour for `ExecuteNonQuery` (there isn't any) check your values and possible exceptions. The only difference between the two functions is that one returns the first available result value while the second does nothing *after execution has finished*.

Comment: So many unknown things so it should be something irrelevant to question. Where you checking DB changes? In your app or sql manager? Are you refreshing data after changes?

Comment: Yes i am refreshing, btw, i am using built in database in c#

Comment: Also make sure you try the query with the same values - that is, make sure you *don't* have extra spaces, newlines etc. What is the *exact* value of `@name` in both cases? Not what you *see* in the textbox but what is the value you pass as a parameter? Are the lengths the same in both cases?

Comment: don't mind the @name i try this query to see if my error is in my parameter `update tbl_userdata set stage=10`

Comment: Only video will help. Btw you dont need stringbuilder and string.format

Comment: @Reniuz, I disagree. Two unit tests with the same values should convince the poster that there's no problem with ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Another possibility is that a transaction is opened in another part of the code but never commited

Comment: What is result of ExecuteNonQuery? It returns effected row count. If 0 - no changes where made.

Comment: Do you have a try/catch block around that code? Can you show the entire method?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'built in database in C#". Where do you try to update data and how you verify it was not?

Comment: Try to run the sanme query in sql server to with the parameter you are giving to verify the update query.
Secondly try to get the sp call from sql profiler to verify the query.
I don't think execute non query is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do as string builder and append in query just use string if values are good with where clause, my answer can be stupid but it is worth of try if you don't find any solution.